# Error with string formatting?

Tags: python, mysql

Having trouble here, It worked when I had multiple (%s,%s) and data was (user,pass) or something like that.

However with the following code I keep getting this error.

```
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Why does this keep happening? It only occurs when there is only a single argument

This code is from my flask application

```
    username = request.values['username']
    update_stmt = (
      "UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET IN_USE = 1 WHERE USER = '(%s)'"
    )

    data = (username)

    cursor.execute(update_stmt,data)
```

Comment: Is this sorted out now?

Answer (score 4):

For a single valued tuple to be recognized as a tuple you need a trailing ,

```
data = (username,)
```

And unrelated, you don't really need to quote in your query

```
"UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET IN_USE = 1 WHERE USER = (%s)"
```

Your full code should be

```
username = request.values['username']
update_stmt = (
  "UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET IN_USE = 1 WHERE USER = (%s)"
)

data = (username,)

cursor.execute(update_stmt,data)
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure I do not need the quotes? Its an email address with a @ in it that was throwing errors if not in quotes, either way I shall try :) Thanks again

Comment: well, i have never used quotes in a prepared statement but your comment caused self doubt and I checked the docs :-) the examples here don't have quotes either: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Does this look simpler? Its giving me an error but for one value it seems more readable update_stmt = ("UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET IN_USE = 1 WHERE USER = '%s'" % username)

        cursor.execute(update_stmt)

Comment: Super similar error though :/ ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: noooooo don't ever use % string formatting in sql that's unsafe.

Comment: What would you suggest? USER = '%s'".format(username))?

Comment: no, please use the exact code i have given above. Don't use string formatting. You have to send the parameters as the second argument to execute. ie there is a world of difference in using % and ,